# spring data mongo db: duplicate key error when extending a base domain class

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, lombok

I've a domain object that extends from BaseDomainObject and it has `Lombok` annotations.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, callSuper = false)
@Document(collection = "SubmissionApplication")
public class SubmissionApplication extends BaseDomainObject {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty("applicationId")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String id;
    private ApplicationSource applicationSource;
    private String applicationCompletionDate;

}
```

BaseDomainObject.java

```
public abstract class BaseDomainObject implements Serializable {
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate;
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;
    private String updateDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedDate;
    @Version
    private Integer version;
    private String createDate;
    private Boolean active = true;
    private String updatedBy;
    private Integer totalCount;

    public BaseDomainObject() {
    }

    .... getters/setters
}
```

and when I try `repo.save(application)` to update existing document, I'm getting exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error collection: APP.SubmissionApplication index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('5f43aef2e878fb1e0b34aab3') }
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1015) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeInsertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:469) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:452) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:446) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.0.4.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.lambda$insertDocument$15(MongoTemplate.java:1442) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:566) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDocument(MongoTemplate.java:1436) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:1236) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:1168) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:84) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
```

If I remove extends BaseDomainObject, spring data mongodb will correctly update the document.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First: how is your question related to Lombok if while removing `extends BaseDomainObject` you don't remove any Lombok annotation from `Application`? Second: you are trying to `update` existing entity but in the stacktrace you can see that `MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne` is invoked. I think it's somehow related to `@Version` annotation of your base class, not Lombok

Comment: my bad, it is not related to lombok, I tried removing all lombok annotation, still getting the same error

Comment: you are right, @Version is causing the problem.  BaseDomainObject comes from another dependency. So cannot make any change to it, and I've to use it  -_-  Anything I can do in the child class that could fix the issue?

Comment: I'd start with inspecting the project code that utilizes other classes derived from this BaseDomainObject. This problem might be solved by other contributors to your project. Otherwise you should provide more details, more sample code

Comment: I was directly using the Model in controller request body and jackson deserializer was setting null value into version. Started using a DTO as request body and issue solved. Thank you Nikolai for pointing me in the right direction.